# "is defined" and "is not null" not working as expected

Tags: twig, operators

I am new to twig and I would like to catch if some product data is not available.
Currently I am trying the following:

```
{% if product.type is defined and product.type is not null %}
    {{ product.type }}
{% endif %}
```

This code throws an exception, that says type is not defined.
Am I missing something? My expectation is that "is defined" should turn out to be false then.

Comment: Is `product` an object or an array?

Comment: It is an object.

Comment: is defined only works on variables or arrays

Comment: I defined product like this: ```{% set product = ... %}```. So it is a variable containing an object. That doesn't work? Is there another possibility then?

Comment: I've chained the function `method_exists` in `twig` to check whether functions exist or not

Comment: is it $type exit in Entity.

Comment: if you `{{ dump(product) }}`, can you see type?